# Question about literature of Alcubierre's drive

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, warp-drives

In the last words of the prepaper*, Mr Alcubierre says:

> As a final comment, I will just mention the fact that even though the spacetime described by the metric (8) is globally hyperbolic, and hence contains no closed causal
>   curves, it is probably not very difficult to construct a spacetime that does contain such
>   curves using a similar idea to the one presented here.

Well, considering that have passed almost 20 years since this arxiv prepaper, exists a article that constructs this kind of spacetime?

(assuming only classical general relativity)

*https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0009013

Answer (score 0):

Guess I found the article, unfortunately. =(

https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.53.7365

Comment: Krasnikov also produced a paper on the topic